# How to play Gbox video in android?

Tags: android

```
{   
    String VideoURL="http://gbox.video/embad/BGb5EDzgR?fs=1&autoplay=1";

    MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
                            Home.this);
                    mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
                    // Get the URL from String VideoURL
                    Uri video = Uri.parse(VideoURL);

                    videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
                    videoview.setVideoURI(video);

                    videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            videoview.start();
                        }
                    });
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain your problem? Are you getting errors? Where are you stuck?